# Read file then store in array without using arraylist java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read a file with 8 columns of data and store each string of data into an array, but I keep getting cannot find symbol error for employee.length. I put 8 elements for each string within the row. Please help me by explaining what I am doing wrong. Code:

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader ("payrollData.dat"));

```
    String employee[] = new String[8];

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < employee.length(); i++)
        {
            employee[i] = scan.next();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(employee);8
```

Comment: Your should learn to use IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans for java development.

Comment: I somewhat know how to use IDEs, but I am a novice programmer and my java instructor prefers we use Notepad++ right now to get familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `employee.length` and not `employee.length()`. In case of arrays, length is a final variable, not a method.

And use `Arrays.toString(employee)` to print employees properly.
`System.out.println(employee)` will just print the reference address.

Comment: Thank you. Another question...how could I call a specific string I'm looking for within the array, like element 0 for example, to store that string into a variable?

Comment: Use indexing. `employee[0]` refers to the first employee. `employee[1]` refers to the second one, and `employee[7]` refers to the last. Doing something like `String x = employee[5]` would give you the sixth employee in `x`. And just as a convention, use `employees` as your array name. It tells that the variable is a collection and not singular.